# How to translate my ASP.NET application using database not with ressource file?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5

I used to use ressource file in the translation section.
Now i want another method in which i will give to the administrator of my .net mvc5 application the ability to add another language and to enter the translation.
I mean i will put a table in  which all the ids and each id have its translation for example id = nameID in the column french = "nom "in th column english = " name"
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended. Because every time the page loads it will have to pick up every word in the database. So with web content mostly text. The query will be very long and many errors occur. Use the file to save the dictionary, such as "Resource file"